# How to show the total per column in tooltip title with c3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3

[image: toke it from c3 official page]

In this case I would like to show 180 instead of 0 on tooltip title. I know that it can be customized like it is done in [c3 official documentation](http://c3js.org/samples/tooltip_format.html). But I don't find the way to get the total per column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just write your own tooltip contents function

```
tooltip: {
    contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
        var sum = 0;
        d.forEach(function (e) {
            sum += e.value
        })
        defaultTitleFormat = function () {
            return sum
        };
        return c3.chart.internal.fn.getTooltipContent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/x0b3w32e/